# How we can we know SQL Replication components installed in SQL server

Tags: sql-server, replication

Can somebody please let me know how can we identify whether Replication components installed in SQL server.

Tried below:

1.we had changed the server name earlier so while checking with configure distributor and publication giving the below warning.

### TITLE: Configure Distribution Wizard

> SQL Server is unable to connect to server 'xxxxxxxx'.

ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:

> SQL Server replication requires the actual server name to make a
>   connection to the server. Specify the actual server name, 'zzzzzzzzz'.
>   (Replication.Utilities)

---

i will rename the server.

2. while tried with configure subscription giving below warning.

### TITLE: New Subscription Wizard

> Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio is unable to access replication
>   components because replication is not installed on this instance of
>   SQL Server. For information about installing replication, see the
>   topic Installing Replication in SQL Server Books Online.

ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:

> Replication components are not installed on this server. Run SQL
>   Server Setup again and select the option to install replication.
>   (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 21028)

Now, Please suggest whether the Replication components installed in SQL instance

Comment: I guess this will be the answer, executed --> EXEC sp_MS_replication_installed

output:

RegOpenKeyEx() returned error 2, 'The system cannot find the file specified.'
Msg 22001, Level 1, State 1
Msg 21028, Level 16, State 1, Procedure sp_MS_replication_installed, Line 35 [Batch Start Line 0]
Replication components are not installed on this server. Run SQL Server Setup again and select the option to install replication.


Any suggestions on this?

Comment: you have to run the SQL Server installation wizard again and install the replication components, check this [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/install-windows/install-sql-server-replication?view=sql-server-2017)

Comment: check [this](https://blog.sqlauthority.com/2018/12/17/sql-server-error-21028-replication-components-are-not-installed-on-this-server/) also

Comment: Yeah, that is workaround, Thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can us the below T-SQL command to query the registry and confirm is Replication Components are installed:

```
USE master;  
GO  
DECLARE @installed int;  
EXEC @installed = sys.sp_MS_replication_installed;  
SELECT @installed;
```

if @installed = 0 then replication is not installed. That stored procedure actually reads the registry using the below command, which is another way of checking:

```
EXEC master.dbo.xp_instance_regread 'HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE',   
        'SOFTWARE\Microsoft\MSSQLServer\Replication',  
        'IsInstalled'
```

[sp_MS_replication_installed example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/availability-groups/windows/configure-replication-for-always-on-availability-groups-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017#step3)

[Underlying code](https://pawjershauge.blogspot.com/2012/05/spmsreplicationinstalled-transact-sql.html)